# Wordpress error in ajax request of wp-admin/admin-ajax.php not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Ive seen many questions on this issue but none of the suggestions have been helpful to me

This is my .htaccess in the root folder

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Previously in my localhost it works but after installing it on a shared hosting the error occurs whenever an ajax request is performed

Ive checked that the file admin-ajax.php is there in the wp-admin folder

When i check on the network tab on the developer tools(chrome) am getting this

```
Request URL:https://mydomainname.com/wp-
 admin/admin-ajax.php
   Request Method:POST
      Status Code:404 Not Found
```

what could be wrong

Comment: How do you get admin-ajax URL in PHP code for ajax?

Comment: ^ that shouldn't matter -- the requested AJAX URL is correct regardless.

Comment: @Ty Bailey: OP said admin-ajax.php file is in folder, but he didn't mentioned about how OP is getting URL of admn-ajax for ajax method.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. He could have a different admin URL. @AshPatel